# Javascript - How to display a specific index of an array on Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I currently have an array of data that I am trying to display on Highcharts.

`const data = [10,31,13,19,21]`

I am having issues with displaying a specific index of an array. For example, I would like one column to be `data: data[0]` the other `data: data[1]` etc.. When doing this I do not have any data displaying on my graph.

I am able to display data when doing `data:data` and displaying the whole array which creates multiple columns but for my situation, like to keep each point in one column.

Here is a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qz3ortbf/)

desired look with specific index of an array i.e. `data: data[1]`:

[image]

---

outcome if using `data: data`

[image]

here is my code:

```
const data = [10,31,13,19,21]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Bar Graph"
    },
    xAxis: {

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value + "%";
        },
        title: {
            text: '% of Total'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Low',
        data: data[0],
        showInLegend: false,
    },{
        name: 'Low',           
        data: data[1]
    },{
        name: 'Medium-Low',
        data: data[2]
    }, {
        name: 'Medium',
        data: data[3]
    }, {
        name: 'Medium-High',
        data: data[4]
    }, {
        name: 'High',
        data: data[5]
    }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` must be an array, meanwhile data[0], data[1], ... are numbers. Instead, you need to assign those values in the array, like: `data: [data[1]]`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ty42b0hs/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Low',
        color: '#0D6302',
        data: [data[0]],
        showInLegend: false,
    },{
        name: 'Low',
        color: '#0D6302',
        data: [data[1]]
    }, ...]
```